# Update single sub document in multiple array in mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

I have following mongodb (3.4.x) document, i code in golang with mgo driver

```
{
"id": "5981d4c2795a1b4a801ee027",
"scenarioId": "59804b10d8ee910085e33865",
"messages": [
    {
        "id": "5981d4c2795a1b4a801ee028",
        "toQueue": [
            {
                "id": "5981d4c2795a1b4a801ee029",
                "to": {
                    "email": "some@email.com"
                },
                "channel": "EMAIL",
                "toType": "EMAIL",
                "status": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "groupId": 1,
                    "groupName": "PROCESSING",
                    "name": "APPROVED",
                    "description": "MessageChain approved for processing"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "5981d4c2795a1b4a801ee02a",
                "to": {
                    "phone": "+381631891245"
                },
                "channel": "SMS",
                "toType": "PHONE",
                "status": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "groupId": 1,
                    "groupName": "PROCESSING",
                    "name": "APPROVED",
                    "description": "MessageChain approved for processing"
                }
            }
        ],
        "status": {
            "id": 1,
            "groupId": 1,
            "groupName": "PROCESSING",
            "name": "APPROVED",
            "description": "MessageChain approved for processing"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "5981d4c2795a1b4a801ee02b",
        "toQueue": [
            {
                "id": "5981d4c2795a1b4a801ee02c",
                "to": {
                    "phone": "+123456789"
                },
                "channel": "SMS",
                "toType": "PHONE",
                "status": {
                    "id": 1,
                    "groupId": 1,
                    "groupName": "PROCESSING",
                    "name": "APPROVED",
                    "description": "MessageChain approved for processing"
                }
            }
        ],
        "status": {
            "id": 1,
            "groupId": 1,
            "groupName": "PROCESSING",
            "name": "APPROVED",
            "description": "MessageChain approved for processing"
        }
    }
],
"messageStages": [
    {
        "id": "5981d4c2795a1b4a801ee033",
        "validityPeriod": 5,
        "validityPeriodTimeUnit": "MINUTES",
        "providerId": 5,
        "email": {
            "text": "this is the email text",
            "subject": "and here the email subject"
        },
        "status": {
            "id": 1,
            "groupId": 1,
            "groupName": "PROCESSING",
            "name": "APPROVED",
            "description": "MessageChain approved for processing"
        }
    }
]
```

}

and I know the value of messages.$.toQueue.id, where i want to update status.id in the related toQueue Array Item.

I tried to do it that way:

```
query = bson.M{
    "messages.toQueue._id": toQueueId,
}

update = bson.M{
    "$set": bson.M{
        "messages.$.toQueue.$.status.id": status.Id,
        "messages.$.toQueue.$.status.name": status.Name,
        "messages.$.toQueue.$.status.groupId": status.GroupId,
        "messages.$.toQueue.$.status.groupName": status.GroupName,
        "messages.$.toQueue.$.status.description": status.Description,

    },
}
err = cr.Update(query,update)
```

but multiple $ are not allowed. Without it's also not updateable.

Is there any way to update only the subdocument, which i found in query ?

Comment: You are trying to update a "nested array". **Don't use "nested arrays"**. The [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) can only match the **"first"** index found, and that **always** means the "outer" array only. You actually **never** need to "nest". Whatever you expect to achieve is **always** better handled by placing "attributes" on the "singular" array items that would represent whatever you "think" the nesting does for you. Nesting does not "categorize". Not the first to ask, and it's a common design mistake. Change the design.

Comment: I agree, that document is way overembedded. A quick gain would be to put the individual messages (email, phone) in an own collection and reference the parent the individual message belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

Neil Lunn gave the right answer.
It's not possible to work with nested arrays the way I tried to do. And he is also right, that problem is coming from design mistake. 
So I changed it as him and Markus W Mahlberg suggested to move the toQueue part in a separate collection, with messageId as a reference.